# Unable to access certain files in Ubuntu?

Tags: permissions, files

I have files in my Ubuntu install that say I am not the owner or do I have the proper permissions to change anything about them.

I completely formatted my hard disk before the Ubuntu installation and told it to use the entire drive for the logical volume.

Can my problem be fixed without completely reinstalling Ubuntu? I'm also having network issues, like extremely slow internet and lots of timeouts.

Please help me! I'm new to Ubuntu and I like it and want to learn how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

First welcome to Ubuntu. Nothing you described sounds abnormal and although it is possible you were "hacked", it is extremely unlikely.

As with any OS it takes some time to understand things that are new and new ways of system administration.

I suggest you start with the following 2 links :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

And then work your way through the official documentation

https://help.ubuntu.com/

Once you have gotten a start, come on back if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score -2):

Easy. You can simply run:

```
sudo chown [[your username]] [[path to directory]]
```

It must be noted that this tool has power. You should only change ownership (if broken) of your home folder.

I had this problem with Apache, in the /var/www folder. This worked there.

Since viruses are so rare in the Ubuntu/linux platform, I would recommend that if this doesn't work, you try reinstalling Ubuntu altogether. Backup your files by copying them to something external, and then use an external image to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: path to directory?  like the files it says i dont own?  the files say they are root files and root is the owner.

Comment: That is horrible advice and a great way to break Ubuntu.

Comment: you shouldn't mess with files owned by root unless you do know what you are doing.